# Is competitor's name in website URL allowed?

Tags: seo, google-ads

Is it allowed to use your competitor's name in a path of your website URL?

For example: If I am competing for the same product as a product name "ABCD" and my product's name is "EFGH".

Can I have a URL www.example.com/abcd-efgh? Also, can I have my competitors name in the title and description tags?

Comment: Hello, are you asking whether this is allowed by law, or as part of an SEO strategy?

Comment: Can you explain in both terms what will exactly happen?

Comment: If your competitor has trademarked their name in your country and elsewhere, you risk legal action for infringing upon their mark.